# How to access route attributes in laravel using route path?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have following route in a package named reports.

```
Route::get('reports/search-beneficiary-details', ['uses' => 'ReportsController@searchBeneficiaryDetails', 'permission' => ['reports.app.reports.search-beneficiary-details', 'Search Details']]);
```

How can I get the permission attribute of the route using the route path?

I can access the current route object in the view as follows and from it i can get permission attribute

```
<?php $routeAtr = Route::getCurrentRoute()->action;dd($routeAtr['permission']) ?>
```

But for any given route path, how can access the permission attribute?

Comment: This might be something to ask the package developer too

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do the trick:

```
// get all routes
$routes = \Route::getRoutes();

// get a single route by name
$route = $routes->getByName($routeName);

// get permission
$routeAtr = $route->action;
dd($routeAtr['permission']);
```

However, if you have multiple routes with the same path but different methods, you need to add method to the equation. In order to do so, you'll need to prepare a Request object and make the router match it against available routes. Try the following code:

```
$request = new Request();
$request->setMethod('post');
$request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', 'some/path');

$routes = \Route::getRoutes();
$route = $routes->match($request);

$routeAtr = $route->action;
dd($routeAtr['permission']);
```

Comment: Still, is there a way to get the route by path?

Comment: You can have multiple routes for a single path. You'd need to add the method to the equation, is that what you need?

Comment: What I need is something like this, `$route = $routes->getByPath('reports/search-beneficiary-details');` or some other way to get the route instance using path

Comment: Again, you can have multiple routes for the same path,how do you want to pick one just based on path?

Comment: Sorry, I just got what were you asking earlier, and in that case yes, I need to use the route method, get, post, etc to pick one.